# What's the correct way to return structured data from a fixture?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Currently I have a setup like this:

```
./
  src/
    mylib.py
  tests/
    __init__.py
    conftest.py
    test_mylib.py
```

`mylib.py` contains:

```py
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

`conftest.py` contains:

```py
import attr
import pytest

@attr.s(slots=True)
class AdditionTestCase:
    input1 = attr.ib()
    input2 = attr.ib()
    output_expected = attr.ib()

@pytest.fixture
def addition_test_case() -> AdditionTestCase:
    # make up some data
    return AdditionTestCase(1, 2, 3)
```

and `test_mylib.py` contains:

```py
from mylib import add
from tests.conftest import AdditionTestCase

def test_add(addition_test_case: AdditionTestCase):
    input1 = addition_test_case.input1
    input2 = addition_test_case.input2
    output_expected = addition_test_case.output_expected

    output_actual = add(input1, input2)
    assert output_actual == output_expected
```

Is this problematic for any reason? Is there a better way to do it? I could move the type definition outside `conftest.py` if importing from it is considered bad practice.

Comment: At the very least, this looks overengineered. What's wrong with `def addition_test_case(): return (1,2,3)` and `input1, input2, output_expected = addition_test_case()`?

Comment: Do you see any problem with it? I frankly would just go with tuples, or `namedtuple`s. IDK if `slots` makes sense; do you have such huge heaps of fixture objects as to save on `__dict__`?. The whole code seems to do the right thing, but could be written shorter. One thing I would add is returning multiple data points from a single fixture function, to test multiple cases succinctly.

Comment: @9000 I use slots as a "code sanity" guarantee, rather than for performance. It's probably paranoid but it helps me sleep at night. And yes, this is "single case" fixture is just for illustration; the real fixture uses Hypothesis to generate fixture data.

Comment: @shadowtalker: Makes sense! I would just wrap it in a function that produces a class for me form a compact declaration: `AdditionTestCase = slotted_class('input1', 'input2', 'output')`, but again, likely `namedtuple` does just that already; it gives you an immutable class with immutable instances that do not allow adding or removing attributes either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

typically this would be solved by just using parameterize without extra types

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("left, right, expected_output", [
   (1, 1, 2),
   (2, 2, 4),
]
def test_add(left, right, expected_output):
  output = add(left, right)
  assert output == expected_output
```